# Extra SQL Statements/Queries: Good or bad idea?

Tags: php, mysql

Each time I execute an SQL query like so:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) VALUES ('$x1', '$x2', '$x3', '$x4', '$x5');";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

I have another query again like so:

```
$query_backup = "INSERT INTO tablename_backup (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) VALUES ('$x1', '$x2', '$x3', '$x4', '$x5');";
mysqli_query($conn, $query_backup);
```

I have 100 tables in my database and for each one I execute two queries, thereby sending the exact same data into two different tables. Is this a good or bad idea according to the standards of good coding practise?

Comment: replication is what you actually want to be doing: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html if its just for a back up i do nightly dumps, this is 'overkill' for most people.

Comment: Redundant data is _generally_ considered bad practice in a database design; the question becomes _why are you/what are to trying to accomplish_ by doing this?

Comment: @smith I could not afford to miss any data. Nightly dumps would not precisely backup all the data (in case some data was deleted during course of the day). Data would be inserted and deleted on an hourly basis, so I figured it would be simpler to have a backup table which can be exported anytime. My question is if this is considered bad practise (overkill) to send an extra query for each table in this case.

Comment: as i said, you want replication.

Comment: That clarifies it then, I will be sure to look into replication. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Don't allow deletes. Just have a 'deleted' flag.